# how to callback angularfire (0.8.2) $firebaseArray to $scope and stay synchronized?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, firebase, angularfire

I am puzzled as how to bind raw data returned by the $loaded promise of angularfire's syncArray to $scope in case I can not simply do an ng-repeat.
I need the raw data to pass it into the angular calendar and there is no ng-repeat for this.

```
$scope.snapshot = fbutil.syncArray("snapshot/" + id)
$scope.events = []
$scope.snapshot.$loaded().then (entries) ->
  angular.forEach entries, ((entry) ->
    @push entry
    return
  ), $scope.events
console.log "$scope.events: ", $scope.events
```

which would output to $scope.events: [] and not bind the inside the promise available entries array to $scope.
It does work with ng-repeat why not via this way?

Comment: Why would you want to create a static (not synchronized) duplicate of the same data and put that into the same $scope? Is that really your intention? This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: It is correct I attempted to address the synchronization problem with a watch function:

snapshot.$watch(function(event) {
  if (!!event) {
    console.log(event);
    return $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
  }
});

This "one way data binding" works for me here because I do not set events on the calendar just display them.
I do see your point with the xy problem and will change the title of this post.

Answer (score -1):

Okay after some more research I stumbled over something for my $scope problem.
It works to some extend with a callback argument in order to hand the transformed data to angular's $scope

```
var resource, snapshot;
snapshot = fbutil.syncArray("snapshot/" + id);
resource = function(callback) {
  return snapshot.$loaded().then(function(entries) {
    var snap;
    snap = [];
    angular.forEach(entries, function(entry) {
      return snap.push({
        title: entry.title,
        start: new Date(entry.start),
        end: new Date(entry.end)
      });
    });
    return callback(snap);
  });
};
$scope.events = resource;
```

Comment: AngularFire doesn't fail silently. It [can also handle date objects](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/381) using $extendFactory. Additionally, your question asks how to put the object into scope, but your answer is about transforming data and doesn't utilize the tools provided by AngularFire, and will not stay properly synchronized.

Comment: Hey Kato thanks for your feedback and the information regarding the date object handling. I will edit my entry and take the bad feedback out of it again. Would you be so kind and point me out a better way to transform the data and avoid the callback method if possible to have that synchronized? Thanks in advance

Comment: Howdy, @enigma, I linked you [to this](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/381) in my last comment. There is a pretty decent discussion there with examples. That's the canonical approach to transform data in synchronized array, and also covered [in the doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-extending-factories). Do you have specific questions beyond what those cover? Because I would simply be parroting that content to answer your question here.